# Can I use both clang and gcc compiler in yosemite?

Tags: command-line, xcode, gcc

I need gcc as a default compiler to compile cuda samples and I need clang to compile my network projects because clang has  better warnings and errors specifications.

Is there any way to run both compilers?

Comment: Why can't you run CUDA in clang? The [cuda install page](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html) implies clang - and mixing two compilers if C++is problamatic and if C then surely which compiler does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Apple's Xcode supplies clang (and puts in /usr/bin/gcc a link to clang not gcc)

Then you can then install gcc - probably the easiest way is via a package manager like Macports, Homebrew or Fink